# How to draw a graph for the set of strings...?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How to draw a graph  that represents the set of strings of 0's and 1's containing

Comment: well, as you suggested, you are missing details.

Comment: To add to Jorge's comment, there should be some restrictions on the graph. Should it be maybe connected? Otherwise you can just take the trivial case of a disconnected graph with an empty edge-set and countable vertex-set.

Comment: You could think of these strings as paths in a  graph with three vertices representing $0$,$1$,$11$, with no edge between $1$ and $11$, edges between the other two pairs of points and a loop at $0$.

Comment: @S.Dolan Why is there no path between 1 and 11? They did not define a relation, so how would I draw the arrows?

Comment: You would not go from 1 to 11 because that would give you three 1s in succession.

Comment: @S.Dolan That makes sense. But then why would we not have self loop at 1 also?

Comment: That would allow you to loop round lots of times and again get lots of 1s.

Comment: @S. Dolan, since I don't know how to add picture into the comments, I edited my question to include a picture. Does it look right?

Comment: Yes that is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Follow any path in the following Digraph from Start to End, recording the character(s) in the square nodes. Edges in a path can be traversed multiple times.

[image]